# How to create a controller in VS 2017 Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-mvc-controller

I installed RTM VS 2017 and created a project:

- Template: ASP.NET Core Web Application (.Net Core)
- ASP.NET Core 1.1 Templates:Web Application
- Right Click Controller, Add, Controller and select Full Dependency
- Right Click Controller, Add, Controller, and select MVC Controller Empty
- Click Add, Add (scaffolding now runs)

I get this error: There was an error running the selected code generator: The specified deps.json [.....bin\HPD\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\myApp.deps.json] does not exist.

I reinstalled VS 2017 just in case I had some kind of corruption but get the same error.  I tried manually adding an empty deps.json in the indicated location but that just leads to a different error because the file is empty.

It would seem that the Full Dependency action should have provided any necessary files.  However, do I need to do something to have this file generated before scaffolding will work?

Comment: Once I ran dotnet restore and ef migrations add Initial then scaffolding worked

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had that problem, but I want to point out there are Nuget packages installed when you select to install MVC Scaffolding `Full Dependencies`.

If you want your application back to the previous state (without Scaffolding), simply uninstall those packages.

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="1.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="1.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design" Version="1.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="1.1.0" />
```

Comment: The point was to use scaffolding.  I suggest that this could be resolved with a different error message that suggested running the restore and ef migration instead of a useless message about an irrelevant deps.json file.  Or, better yet, selecting Full Dependency could just do this automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
Copy all the files from bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1 to bin\MCD\Debug\netcoreapp1.1 resolves the issue.